# How to hide the title bar in the iPhone main window

Tags: iphone

This question might be very easy to answer so I apologize if I missed the obvious.
I'm developing a GUI application on the iPhone and want to hide the title/status bar of the iPhone which usually displays the carrier/time/battery.
How can I do this from within the code given the main UIWindow and UIView?

-A

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your Info.plist file, set `UIStatusBarHidden` to true or add the following to your application delegate:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
```

Comment: The Info.plist option worked best for me, as my table view then filled the entire screen, where the code option just hid the bar and there was white space at the top of the app.  The code option also is now deprecated.

Comment: If you're using new Xcode - the item to edit in the plist file is "Status bar is initially hidden"

Answer (score 2):

The answers above are deprecated.  The right way to do this programmatically is now:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES 
                                   withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone] ;
```

If you want you could use `UIStatusBarAnimationFade` or `UIStatusBarAnimationSlide` instead of `UIStatusBarAnimationNone`

Answer (score 2):

## prefersStatusBarHidden

Specifies whether the view controller prefers the status bar to be hidden or shown.

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return YES;
}
```

---

UIViewController Class Reference

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/Documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/prefersStatusBarHidden

Answer (score 1):

As at writing of this replies, Xcode 4.1, just use the following:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:TRUE];
```

will not have white space at the top.

alternatively, the plist entry is:

"Status bar is initially hidden"